# Number of unique outputs in hash function (SHA256) against all possible inputs

Tags: hash, sha-256

If I use SHA256 as a hash function, and I try all inputs starting from 0 to 2^256 (means all possible combination of 256-bit), then will it give me 2^256 unique output without any collision?

Or in other words, does 2^256 different inputs maps to 2^256 different output in SHA256?